# Is there anything wrong with using BeginRenderLink and changing the querystring parameters with a controller rendering?

Tags: glass-mapper

Right now in our view we have something like this:

```
using (BeginRenderLink(x => x.ButtonLink, new { @class = "primary-button", style = style }, isEditable: true))
{
    @Editable(x => x.ButtonText)
}
```

We're currently linking to this view from a view rendering and the business has told me that they may want to occasionally add a Querystring parameter to the link and that the value may depend on several factors.

I'm considering changing the rendering to a controller so that I can change `x.ButtonLink` to include the query string parameters I want.

What I am concerned with is how to get this to play well with the experience editor. Am I going about this the wrong way? Is there a different method I should use that would serve this purpose better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a good approach that you mentioned in the question. As far as I see you are using Glass Mapper, so this `ButtonLink` is a `Link` type where you can easily change the `Query` property in your Controller, like this:

```
model.ButtonLink.Query = "key=value";
```

Important to mention that with the approach above you overwrite the querystring which can be given by content editors.